# DatabaseUtils: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to touch /mnt/media_rw/3365-3139/DCIM/Camera/.VID.mp4.tmp: java.io.IOException

Tags: android, android-sdcard

When i want to create a file in sdcard.

DatabaseUtils: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to touch /mnt/media_rw/3365-3139/DCIM/Camera/.VID_20190422_031234844.mp4.tmp: java.io.IOException: Read-only file system

I have add permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```java
DocumentFile file = file = sdcardCameraDir.createFile("image/jpeg", ".VID_20190422_031234844.mp4.tmp");
```

This is exception:

```
04-22 03:12:34.860 24561 24844 E DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
04-22 03:12:34.860 24561 24844 E DatabaseUtils: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to touch /mnt/media_rw/3365-3139/DCIM/Camera/.VID_20190422_031234844.mp4.tmp: java.io.IOException: Read-only file system
04-22 03:12:34.860 24561 24844 E DatabaseUtils:     at com.android.internal.content.FileSystemProvider.createDocument(FileSystemProvider.java:219)
04-22 03:12:34.860 24561 24844 E DatabaseUtils:     at android.provider.DocumentsProvider.callUnchecked(DocumentsProvider.java:1005)
04-22 03:12:34.860 24561 24844 E DatabaseUtils:     at android.provider.DocumentsProvider.call(DocumentsProvider.java:951)
04-22 03:12:34.860 24561 24844 E DatabaseUtils:     at com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider.call(ExternalStorageProvider.java:611)
04-22 03:12:34.860 24561 24844 E DatabaseUtils:     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:403)
04-22 03:12:34.860 24561 24844 E DatabaseUtils:     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:272)
04-22 03:12:34.860 24561 24844 E DatabaseUtils:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:748)
```

I can get the BroadcastReceiver of SdCard has been mounted (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED); but i can not create file in SdCard.

How can I detect that I can't create a file on Sdcard?